# Comma before and after "and" and again after non-essential information?

Tags: grammar, commas, conjunctions

I always have trouble figuring out how to punctuate these kinds of sentences (the commas in particular). I feel like the first example should be correct, but the commas also seem excessive. What do you think, and why?

She stopped buying coffee at the cafe by her house every morning, and, by doing so, she's been able to save a bit of money.

She stopped buying coffee at the cafe by her house every morning and, by doing so, she's been able to save a bit of money.

She stopped buying coffee at the cafe by her house every morning, and by doing so, she's been able to save a bit of money.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

@Kiki89, Welcome to English Stackexchange.

Your third sentence is the correct one.  In the first example you cited above, the second comma is used where you might pause while reading the sentence.

Many writers have been told to use a comma anytime they would pause while reading a piece of writing.  While following this suggestion will lead to correct comma usage in some situations, there are many other times when following this guideline will lead to unnecessary comma usage.

> Use a comma to separate independent clauses linked with
>   coordinating conjunctions. If you have what can be two separate
>   sentences but want to make them one (creating a compound sentence),
>   use a comma and a coordinating conjunction (for, and, nor, but, or,
>   yet, so) to link them.  (More information on compound sentences) The
>   comma should be placed in front of the coordinating conjunction.
>
> Examples:
>
> My English Instructor was a good teacher, and he taught me a lot about
>   the writing process. We left the house later than we hoped, but we
>   still made it to the concert on time

In your second sentence, the comma should come before the 'and'.

> Use a comma to set off nonessential elements. A nonessential element
>   is a word, phrase, or clause that is not needed to complete a
>   sentence.  In other words, it can be removed and the sentence still
>   makes sense and is grammatically correct.  If removing the element
>   changes the meaning of the sentence, it is essential.  Nonessential
>   elements need to be offset with commas, both before and after.
>
> Examples of nonessential elements:
>
> I went to the movies with my neighbors, Ron and Sally, and then we
>   went to dinner. The students in my morning class, ENG 121, like to
>   participate in the discussions. Her best friend, Heather, is planning
>   a surprise party for her birthday.

Comma rules are explained here:
https://www.aims.edu/student/online-writing-lab/grammar/comma-rules

I hope this helps.